# Adding Google API to custom Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-cloud-platform

the Google maps function on my company's location pages are showing up with an error message. I have discovered that this is from not an API Key. So, I went onto Google Cloud Platform and cread an API Key to insert into the locations page code. The site was built by someone before me and this is the only info I can find in the code that suggest APIs:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function(){
wp_register_script( 'googlemaps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp', array(), null, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'googlemaps' );
wp_register_script( 'locationscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/location.scripts.js', array( 'jquery' ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'locationscript' );
```

});

Google cloud platform directed me to insert this code:

```
 <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAjvClACTahW6B2ATZXq5ZM-rpSG4ThtLk&callback=initMap"
 type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've tried inserting this code on my locations page but the maps still come with errors. I've also tried switching the

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp'
```

to:

```
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jjs?key=AIzaSyAjvClACTahW6B2ATZXq5ZM-rpSG4ThtLk&callback=initMa'
```

but to no avail. Any ideas?

Comment: You mention in your question that you're seeing some errors. Which ones?

Comment: There's a bubble over the map saying "This page can't load Google Maps correctly."